# Latitude and longitute in Haversine show wrong distance in mysql

Tags: mysql, geolocation, latitude-longitude, haversine

I really wanna know why place B is more far than place C to place A, when i use Haversine formula, but when i see on the map the place C is more distant, i will show some data:

```
Place A - lat: -23.598593 lon:-46.644701
Place B - lat: -23.575966 lon:-46.619133 to A distance = 3.6117730949107836
Place C - lat: -23.594992 lon:-46.636688 to A distance = 0.9068309093558656
```

[image: Distance relative on google map]
I'm using this query :

QUERY A to B

```
set @latdest = -23.575966;
set @londest = -46.619133;
set @lat = -23.598593;
set @lon = -46.644701;
select 6353 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@lat - @latdest) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)
       + COS(@lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(@latdest * pi()/180)
       * POWER(SIN((@lon - @londest) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
```

QUERY A to C

```
set @latdest = -23.594992;
set @londest = -46.636688;
set @lat = -23.598593;
set @lon = -46.644701;
select 6353 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@lat - @latdest) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)
       + COS(@lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(@latdest * pi()/180)
       * POWER(SIN((@lon - @londest) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
```

Comment: B certainly looks further to A than C, from what I can tell.

Comment: Have you considered that your math is correct but your map is not? `Lat -23.5985` (Point A in your math) is obviously the most southern point, yet on your map it is the most northern point, while `lon -46.644701` (point A in your math) is the most western point, while on the map, it is in between the other two.

Comment: 23°35'54.9"S 46°38'40.9"W is Metro Hospital Sao Paolo. Point A iscloser to FIAP at 23°34'25.7"S 46°37'22.8"W

Comment: Oh sorry, the map has been updated. But the distance still visible.

Comment: Again, 'A' is not where you claim it is: https://www.google.com/maps/place/23%C2%B035'54.9%22S+46%C2%B038'40.9%22W/@-23.5993727,-46.658548,14.94z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-23.598593!4d-46.644701

Comment: You're not using your 'common sense'. Solarflare has already explained this but perhaps it bears repetition: -23.598 = South 23.598; so the southernmonst of your coordinates. -46.645 = West 46.645; so the westernmost of your coordinates; so it's obvious that the relative positions of your objects is incorrect.

Comment: You guys are right. I got place A coordinate from mapbox geocoder, but in google maps i was input by address. Haversine it's ok